# Amarok / Clementine alternative

Tags: music-player

Is there a music player or a functionality in Amarok or Clementine that allows to update the ID3 tag of the files in my library that stores the changes in the library database only, leaving the original file intact?

I know it's a weird question but I have in my collection some sfv hashed folders and I would like to leave the files there intact while being able to alter the tags appearing in the music player's library.

Another reason is that some folders are in the local network and write access is disabled.

Comment: This might also be useful for files shared by bittorrent. You could edit the tags to your liking and it wouldn't change the checksums. Now, I have to copy the files to another location and edit them there. The kicker would be knowing what to do with the database if the files are on a removable store that is not currently mounted.